# Domain driven design: entity creation, unnecessary properties?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm currently developing my first project using domain-driven design, and I'm running into some challenges with entity construction. Specifically, I have an Event entity that has a multitude of properties, some of which are optional and others that require certain invariants to be enforced.

Here's a simplified version of the Event entity's properties:

```
Id
OwnerId
Name
Description (optional)
AttendeeList
InviteList (optional)
Visibility (public/private)
StartDateTime
EndDateTime
RSVP deadline (optional)
Max Capacity (optional)
[Other properties]
```

As I'm modeling the entity, I'm questioning whether I should include all these properties in the constructor, especially considering that not all properties are relevant for every use case. Some of the properties are optional, but if set, then some invariants need to be enforced, for example if the max capcity is set and exceeded then you can not add more attendees. Then there are some properties like description that have no invariants, they can just be set and updated.

**My first question:**

Should i be passing all these properties including 'description' everytime i retrieve the Event entity for every use case. For example, when a participant changes their attendance status to 'attending' then i need to check for max capacity to make sure the entity is always in a valid state,but there is nevery any use case with business logic relatiing to the 'description', the description is only ever set initially or updated. Should the description property not be apart of the event entity, and instead just updated CRUD style?

**Second question:**

Should optional fields that have a default value be left out of the constructor and when constructing/hydrating the domain enetity, just be set with setter methods?

**Third and last question:**

Regaring the dependency inverions rule and keeping a valid entity state. The name property has an invariant that needs to be enforced, the name must be unique to all other event names. There are multiple steps where i can check if the proposed name is not already taken, form validation, in the application service for entity creation/update, in the factory etc, but ultimately, to completely enure that the entity name is always valid it should be a responsibility of the entity it self right? Which then would require the entity to somehow depend on a service to check the name is unique against all other entities. Or is it just enough to only restrict entity creation/intiliasation through application service -> repository -> factory and have the factory do the name validation check first before passing the name to the entity object.

Am i thinking about this correctly?